# Meaning of "Like night follows day"

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, british-english, idioms, spoken-english

> And, like night follows day, here it is. The complete silence.

What does this phrase mean? it's from a novel called "I've got your no".

Comment: Please provide greater context.  Is it from a song, poem, or script?

Answer (score 4):

Night follows day **inevitably**, **always**, **predictably**.

The sentence

> And, like **night follows day**, here it is.

uses the simile (likening of one thing to the other) to suggest certain traits of the "other thing" that are the same as in the first one.  In that sentence "here it is" states the fact that something ("it") has become available for observation, appeared to be seen/felt.  The simile alludes to the inevitability or predictability of "it" being "here" by comparing it to the occurrence of night after day.

The second [incomplete] sentence

> The complete silence.

explains what "it" is in the first sentence.