# Is there an idiom that means "it was something inevitable"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "it was something inevitable"? I am not sure if it's the case, but there's this idiom, it was something like "this was ought to happen", but it was an actual idiom instead of just a phrase and I don't remember what it was exactly, I had it on the tip of the tongue, but I have it no more.

Comment: "No one else had expected the factory to close, but **we saw it coming**."

Comment: Does it have something with destiny or fate or is it threatening (impending)? In what context you imagine to use the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Imminent** means *likely to occur at any moment; impending* ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/imminent)).

> The birth of her child was imminent.

**On the verge** *If you are on the verge of something or come to the verge of something, you are very close to experiencing it* ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/on-the-verge-of)).

> on the verge of success

Answer (score 1):

The die is cast.
The action was set in motion.

Comment: On this site you need to provide links and explanations for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> [Like night follows day](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73232).
>
> Like the sun rising in the East.
>
> Like [death and taxes](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/the_difference_between_death_and_taxes_is_that_death_doesnt_get_worse_every/).

Answer (score 0):

"[The event] was bound to happen."

Comment: While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].